# This is only goodbye

Tags: discussion

This is with a heavy heart that I've writing this post. I am handing in my resignation as a moderator for IPS.SE today, which means my diamond will be removed soon. A lot has been happening IRL and I find myself unable to dedicate enough time for the duties that come with being a moderator for a Stack.

I cannot thank you all enough for what this site and the interactions we've had together has brought me. I grew as a person, and learned a lot on interpersonal skills even when I thought I was the one providing advice.

I'll drop by as often as I can, both to answer posts I can help with and because I've made real friends along the way.

Farewell, and long live IPS! ♥

Answer (score 9):

I was wondering why I wasn't seeing you around anymore as it used to be, I now have the answer :(

Thanks for the time, effort and dedication to our stack.
Wish you the best. Good luck for everything and whenever needed, hope to see you around sometimes :)

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for the work you've done, ava, and good luck with your IRL stuff! The service you've provided to the site is valued and your efforts won't be forgotten.

I hope we'll see you around whenever possible, including over at TAS.

Answer (score 4):

I know I wasn't around a lot recently but you have always struck me as a very nice person and IPS has most definitely lost a good mod with you being gone. I wish you all the best and I hope we run into each other again some time.

Cheers to you!

Answer (score 2):

I logged in just to write this. Thank you for your contributions to the community. I wish you the best, and may you have your real-life matters under control, and find the time to continue visiting the site in the future as well.

I have had a hectic time in the past few years as well, and could not involve in many of the conversations here. But I did lurk around and hope to continue the same way.